# Variable naming inside l3keys

Tags: expl3, naming, variable, l3keys

I have a question about naming variables. In `expl3`, the variable naming convention is the following: `\<scope>_<module>_<description>_<type>`. The `<scope>` can be `l`, `g`, or `c`, which indicates whether the variable is a local, global, or constant variable (although this is technically not enforced; it is just a convention).

I am currently writing a package where I set up variables using `l3keys`. These variables have an initial value set by the `.initial:` key. In this situation, I am unsure whether I should use `g` or `c` as the variable scope. One could argue `c` would be appropriate since I would like the variable's value never to change after it is loaded via the package option. Or perhaps `g` would be best since, if my understanding is correct, the variable can change from the initial value set by `.initial:n` to the value set by the user when loading the package options.

EDIT: I've updated my MWE.

Here is the main file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mypackage}
\begin{document}
Some text.

%I am aware that using \ExplSyntax is bad practice inside the document body.
%This is solely for demonstration.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_use:N \c_mymodule_testdimen_dim
\par
\skip_use:N \c_mymodule_testskip_skip
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Here is the package file named `mypackage.sty`.

```
\ProvidesExplPackage
    {mypackage}
    {2023-07-01}
    {1.0.0}
    {Test package}
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
{
    testdimen .dim_gset:N = \c_mymodule_testdimen_dim
    ,testdimen .initial:n = { 12pt }
    ,textskip .skip_gset:N = \c_mymodule_testskip_skip
    ,textskip .initial:n = { 12pt plus 6pt minus 3pt }
}
\ProcessKeyOptions
```

Comment: No, I am not using the package `l3keys2e` because it is obsolete. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3keys2e

Comment: `l3keys` is documented in the `l3kernel`. See the file `interface3.pdf.` https://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel Also I should clarify that my question is about variable naming conventions and not about "how to do x."

Comment: Because the user can change the values, and the values are usable anywhere in the package, I would use a global variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

User-defined values are never constants, as you are *setting* an existing *variable* not creating them in one go. As you are setting globally, you should use `\g_...` not `\l_...`. (You can't really have a constant set from a key, as the variable has to be created when the key is, so has one value, then is being altered when you set the key.)

Of course, TeX doesn't have formal constants, but the `expl3` convention for these are they are programmer-specified global values that do no change. Thus `\c_...` is for things like pre-defined sizes of data structures that never change, locations of csnames that are fixed. (*E.g.* `l3keys` itself for example uses a set of constant `tl` to set where keys are stored.) They are in that sense not just 'set once for this TeX run' but 'set for all uses of this code on the same setup (engine, platform, etc.)'.

Comment: So font size would be a global variable in a standard class but a constant in a class which specified it with no other option? Also, where is the new `\ProcessKeyOptions` documented? I tried searching interface3.pdf and expl3.pdf, but haven't had any luck.

Comment: @cfr I;d say it's a value judgement but I'd stick with `g`: it's not something that's hard-fixed in the same way an array size is.

Comment: @cfr Documentation is in `clsguide` as it's a 2e feature

Comment: Thanks. I was looking in the wrong places.